# Are people rarely saving answers?

Tags: discussion, saves

If we see go to the badges page, and scroll down to the Answers section, we'll see something like this, where there's rarely (currently 1) any badges given out for saved answers:

[image]

- [Favorite Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/11220/favorite-answer)
- [Stellar Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/11221/stellar-answer)

The answer that was awarded this badge is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/18244921) which is not surprising. However, what is surprising is that there are so few of these badges given out. Do people just not save answers (and only questions)? How could we encourage saving of answers? I think most people tend to save the question instead of the answer, which makes sense, but it kinda detracts from the point of being able to save an answer.

Or is this a bug where the new [Saves](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/10/04/meet-saves-the-tool-to-help-you-organize-your-favorite-content-on-stack-overflow/) feature wiped out the previously bookmarked answers? (I don't know as I did not pay attention to this before Saves were added.)

Comment: We _just_ got the feature to save answers. Users already have "saved" questions because their bookmarks (previously only available to questions) were _automatically_ converted into Saves. So, of course, questions have a massive head start.

Comment: Only one answer has reached a score of over 100 in the past month, for an answer to be saved 25 times within a month it'd have to be quite a popular answer... that's just not something that happens regularly.

Comment: _"Or is this a bug where the new Saves feature wiped out the previously bookmarked answers"_ There were no previously bookmarked answers.

Comment: Of course the first answer to get awaded with the new badge is the [horribly disputed regex answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5515060) <chuckles>

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [saves feature was released on the 6th of October](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382019/bookmarks-have-evolved-into-saves) . Part of the feature is allowing saving answers which has been [a long outstanding feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2588/mark-answer-as-favorite-star).

From [the announcement post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382019/bookmarks-have-evolved-into-saves):

> An overview of the new features you'll see with Saves:
>
> - The ability to save answers

and also further down in the FAQ section:

> **Are you adding any new badges?**
>
> Absolutely! With the ability to save answers now, we will be adding two new badges for you to earn: Favorite Answer (Silver Badge) and Stellar Answer (Gold Badge), awarded when answers are saved by 25 and 100 users, respectively. The [badge list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges) will be updated to reflect these new additions.
>
> **What happens to the existing badges I’ve earned with the previous bookmarks feature?**
>
> We will be carrying over the existing badge progress associated with the [Favorite Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/33/favorite-question) and [Stellar Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/34/stellar-question) badges.

All question bookmarks have been migrated as question saves and the badge for questions was retained. However, saving answers is a feature available for only 20 days, at present.

Between the lack of any prior saved answers and the time users will need to get used to the new functionality to save answers, it will naturally take time for the badge related to answers to start showing up more.